# nth-child on cards to achieve alternation

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to achieve that alternating look to my cards where the image and text switch sides every second element.

To do this I tried selecting the `card` class with `:nth-child(even)` and `:nth-child(2)` with no luck.

Here's my code

```css
    .my-card {
      display: flex;
      ...
    } 
    
    .my-card:nth-child(even) {
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
```

```html
   <div id='card-list'>
      <div class='my-card'>
        <img src='#' />
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    
      <div class='my-card'>
        <img src='#' />
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    
      <div class='my-card'>
        <img src='#' />
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Without looking at the HTML to make sure, the given `:nth-child(even)` example should select all even numbered children. It's possible that `flex-direction` doesn't do what you think it does. You could try attributing a border color to every second element (e.g.: `border: 1px solid orange`) to see if the elements are being selected correctly.

Comment: @JoaoCostaIFG I updated my question. Also border had no effect.

Comment: I tested the code here and it seems to be working: https://syncfiddle.net/fiddle/-MT6wuMwLxkn2TpD9CgF . Are you sure you're including the stylesheet in your HTML?

Comment: What's the problem? In your snippet it works as expected: the `flex-direction: row-reverse;` is applied to the second `.my-card` element only

Answer (score 0):

change the css slightly to apply the flex `order` to the `img` nested within each card.

This way you're selecting each card with the `:nth-child(even)` but only applying the css to the nested `<img>` tag

```css
.my-card {
      display: flex;
    } 
    
.my-card:nth-child(even) img{
    order: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div id='card-list'>
      <div class='my-card'>
        <img src='#' />
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    
      <div class='my-card'>
        <img src='#' />
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    
      <div class='my-card'>
        <img src='#' />
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```